# How To Fix height dt and dd when there is no words

Tags: html, css

I am fixing the table (dd and dt) here, the line between every row in dt seems broken when there is nothing? What should I change/add in the css ?

here is the whole file

```
<template>
    <div class="nc-address-card" data-cy="address-card">
        <dl>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.postalCodde }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['postal_code'] }}</dd>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.prefecture }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['prefecture'] }}</dd>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.cityTown }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['city_town'] }}</dd>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.houseName }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['house_num'] }}</dd>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.buildingName }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['building_name'] }}</dd>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.companyName }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['company_name'] }}</dd>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.departmentName }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['department_name'] }}</dd>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.staffName }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['staff_name'] }}</dd>
            <dt>{{ $ncs.telephoneNum }}</dt><dd>{{ sender['telephone_num'] }}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    dl {
      width: 41rem;
    }
    dt, dd {
      border-bottom: solid 1px $gray;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 150%;
      padding: 0.5rem 1.3rem;
      margin: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      &:nth-child(1), &:nth-child(2) {
        border-top: solid 1px $gray;
      }
    }

    dt {
      width: 10rem;
      background-color: $table-header;
    }
    dd {
      width: 30rem;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: it will really help if you post HTML code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the vertical align property with the value top, to align the inline-blocks to the top. This will fix your issue.

```
 dt, dd {
       border-bottom: solid 1px $gray;
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: top;
 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: thank you verymuch, but it's the opposite lol, once again thank you verymuch :D